# sqlite data file encrypt

Tags: iphone

I hope to encrypt sqlite file which store my app data.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few commercial options which provide add-ons to SQLite for encryption.  The most likely candidate is:

- The [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) which is developed by the original author of SQLite. This is distributed as source and can be compiled for any platform.  In this way, you could compile your own embedded version of SQLite instead of using the system one.  It provides both RC4 and AES encryption.

There are two other products, but appear to require Windows:

- [SQLiteCrypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/) - AES encryption
- [SQLite-Encrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/) - AES encryption

Both seem to have very similar features, but it isn't clear if you get the source to recompile on iOS.